# opencsv can't read a file what has unwanted double quote in text

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
"first", "abc", "def", "last"
"111", "abc", "p"roblem", "last"
"aaa", "abc", "456", "last"
```

As you can see the second row has an extra double quote in text.

I am using below constructor:

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("temp.csv"), ',', '"', '|', 1);
```

Program fails because of that extra " in 2nd row.

How can I workaround this problem. I can't change the csv.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exception you're getting. I used `CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("q.csv"));` It is reading..

Comment: There is no exception but reader.readNext() returns invalid tockens. it assumes the end of token at "p" and messup up rest of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file contains `double quotes` should be escaped. I've changed the 2nd line to

`"111", "abc", "pr\"oblem", "last"`

it is working. You can try this. 
and http://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php this may help a little more.

Comment: As I have already mentioned I can not change csv file. I am looking for a solution without touching csv file.